# How to replace an expression in an entire notebook?

Tags: replacement

I have a frequently occurring complex expression, let's for simplicity say $a+b$ which I want to **replace** with let's say $c$ in all the mathematical expressions following this *Rule*. It is simply like naming an obtained expression a certain name in the entire notebook wherever it appears upon evaluation automatically. I know that we can use the *ReplaceAll* function for each cell. But for that, we already need to know where this expression will occur. I don't want to put *ReplaceAll* in all the many expressions. I want to do it in general for all complicated expressions where I want this $a+b$ to be replaced with $c$ even when I am not aware of its occurrence in highly complex expressions.

Comment: If you say in the `Notebook` do you mean like using the Find-and-Replace dialog? That's what it sounds like to me...

Comment: Or do you mean that you want every complicated expression such as `a + (x*y) + b` rewritten to `c + (x*y)` ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes that is what I wanna do precisely but do that for the entire Notebook without doing it for each cell individually.